# Balancing a wobbling table

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I recently taught a basic real analysis class and showed, as an application of the intermediate value theorem, that a wobbling square table (whose feet lie in a plane) can be balanced by rotating it (if you rotate the table by 90 degrees, then the opposite diagonal is wobbling than was initially wobbling).

I then asked about generalizations to non-square tables. This seems to be addressed in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511490. To make the problem more tractable, I asked the students to consider a closely related problem:

Let $h(x,y)$ be a continuous function of two variables. Then show that there are 4 points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ forming a $2\times 1$ rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$ (labelled in order around the perimeter) such that $h(A)-h(B)=h(D)-h(C)$ [that is $(A,h(A))$, $(B,h(B))$, $(C,h(C))$, $(D,h(D))$ lie in a plane.

Given 4 points $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ forming a rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$, I call the *warp* the quantity $h(A)-h(B)+h(C)-h(D)$. The key observation is that if a rectangle decomposes into other rectangles, then the warp of the large rectangle is the sum of the warps of the sub-rectangles.

This allows us to show that there is a $2\times 1$ rectangle with zero warp as required above: there exists a $2\times 2$ rectangle with zero warp by the rotation argument above. Now divide it in half. If one half has a positive warp, the other half has a negative warp. Now use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

A similar argument works for a $p\times q$ rectangle if $p$ and $q$ are integers.

> How about a $\sqrt 2\times 1$ rectangle

EDIT: There is a positive answer if $h(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous just by arranging the boxes to approximate a square. Also if $h(x,y)$ is bounded (just make any large rectangular arrangement of boxes; if the warps of the sub-boxes all have the same sign, they must be small in order that the large box has bounded warp).

EDIT: the MSE posting referred to by @TonyK below seems to have a nice answer to this question, based on integrating the warp as the table is rotated through 360 degrees (or 180 degrees).

Comment: I asked [a similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17870/767) on mathoverflow ten years ago. You might like to take a look.